# C function with two pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference

Hello I have a problem with one function. The Declaration is:

```
int load_clusters(char *filename, struct cluster_t **arr)
```

And i dont know how to work with these 2 pointers before **arr.
I expect that i call it like this:

```
struct cluster_t *clusters;
load_clusters("file.txt",&clusters);
```

But I'm not sure if it is correct or not.

In the function I need to alocate memory for it.
I think it have to be like this.

```
 arr = (struct cluster_t**)malloc(count * sizeof(struct cluster_t*));
 arr[0...x] = (struct cluster_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct cluster_t));
 arr[0...x]->size += 1;
.
.
.
```

But after all this I need to call function to print clusters.

```
 void print_clusters(struct cluster_t *carr, int narr)
{
    printf("Clusters:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < narr; i++)
    {
        printf("cluster %d: ", i);
        print_cluster(&carr[i]); AND THIS DOESN'T WORK AS I EXPECT
    }
}
```

Thank for all help ;-)

Comment: Usually, ** means that the function will allocate memory and wants to return a pointer to the allocated memory, so you need to pass a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `load_clusters`, `arr` is a local variable, so any changes made to it are not reflected in the caller.

What you have is the address of a pointer variable you want to assign to.  So dereference it and allocate space for an array of `struct cluster_t`.

```
*arr = malloc(count * sizeof(struct cluster_t));
```

Also, [don't cast the return value of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).